# Looping through a multi-dimentional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

Initially, I was using a backend-as-a-service (Baas) to collect and simply display data on a webpage via a REST API call. The data was in JSON and decoded into a one dimensional array. I used the code below to successfully loop through the array and display the 'text' values in the array one line at a time on a webpage:

```
$returned_content = get_data('https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Alerts');     //returns JSON

$data = json_decode($returned_content); //JSON to array

foreach ($data->results as $item) {

    echo '<p>'.$item->text;
}
```

I switched BaaS providers and now the JSON when decoded is in a multi-dimensional array. An extract of the output is below:

```html
array (
  'offset' => 0,
  'data' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'created' => 1486047487000,
      '___class' => 'Alerts',
      'text' => 'Thank you for attending the 2017 BICSI Winter Conference and Exhibition in Tampa, FL.',
      'ownerId' => NULL,
      'updated' => NULL,
      'objectId' => '610DF2CC-B333-4BAA-FF93-224B8273B100',
      '__meta' => '{"relationRemovalIds":{},"selectedProperties":["created","___class","text","ownerId","updated","objectId"],"relatedObjects":{}}',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'created' => 1486047378000,
      '___class' => 'Alerts',
      'text' => 'Thank you for attending the 2017 BICSI Winter Conference and Exhibition in Tampa, FL.',
      'ownerId' => NULL,
      'updated' => NULL,
      'objectId' => '43B5620F-2A19-5575-FF9F-B952AB2F0A00',
      '__meta' => '{"relationRemovalIds":{},"selectedProperties":["created","___class","text","ownerId","updated","objectId"],"relatedObjects":{}}',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'created' => 1476139578000,
      '___class' => 'Alerts',
      'text' => 'test5 pw and backendless',
      'ownerId' => NULL,
      'updated' => NULL,
      'objectId' => '97B1BC3A-3233-2265-FF73-752BA720F300',
      '__meta' => '{"relationRemovalIds":{},"selectedProperties":["created","___class","text","ownerId","updated","objectId"],"relatedObjects":{}}',
    ),
  ),
   'nextPage' => 'https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Alerts?pageSize=10&offset=10',
   'totalObjects' => 44,
)
```

I am not a pro in PHP and I cannot figure out how to loop through this multi-dimensional array and simply display the 'text' values like I did with the one dimensional array. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar:

```
foreach ($data['data'] as $item) {

    echo '<p>'.$item['text'];
}
```

1. The notation is different use `$array['key']` for the equivalent of `$object->key`
2. Whatever was in `$data->results` is now in `$data['data']`.

That' should be it.

I might call `json_decode(json_encode($dataArray))` to get a stdClass project representation of the array. Sometime working with `->` notation is just easier.

Just noticed you were kind of mixing up, array and object terms. I think the new BaaS just uses a different key for the actual data. Try this:

```
$returned_content = get_data('https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Alerts');     //returns JSON

$data = json_decode($returned_content['data']); //JSON to array

foreach ($data as $item) {

    echo '<p>'.$item->text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. You pointed me in the right direction. This is what worked using the 'true' parameter in json_decode and your foreach code you provided at the beginning of your answer:  `$returned_content =       get_data('https://api.backendless.com/v1/data/Alerts');     //returns JSON  
$data = json_decode($returned_content, true); //JSON to array  
foreach ($data ['data']as $item) {  
    echo '<p>'.$item['text'];  
}  
?>`